# Add row to Spark Dataframe with timestamps and id

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe named `timeDF` which has the schema below:

```
root
 |-- Id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Model: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Prevision: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I want to add a new row at the end of `timeDF` by transforming two `Calendar` objects `c1` & `c2` to `Timestamp`. I know I can do it by first converting them to `Timestamp` like so :

```
val t1 = new Timestamp(c1.getTimeInMillis)
val t2 = new Timestamp(c2.getTimeInMillis)
```

However, I can't figure out how I then write those variables to `timeDF` as a new row, and how to let spark increase the `Id` column value ?

Should I create a `List` object with `t1` and `t2` and make a temporary dataframe from this list to then union the two dataframes ? If so how do I manage the `Id` column ? Isn't it too much a mess for such a simple operation ?

Can someone explain me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Adrien, Spark is not a database so you cannot really do an insert like you would do with with a relational database. What you can do is create a new dataframe, unionByName() it to your timeDf, and then add the id using Spark’s dataframe API. Depending on your concurrency situation, the is could be troublesome.

Comment: @jgp Okay I4ll try it but for the id I don't really understand what to do. If I merge the timeDF to the temporary dataframe (which has 2 columns) the id will be null isn't it ?

Comment: It's ok to have nulls, you can filter on them, change their values (by creating another column, yes, Spark is not a database :) ). Do you have to worry about concurrency when you create your new rows?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try, in a nutshell:

1. Ingest your file.
2. Create a new dataframe with your data and `unionByName()`.
3. Correct the id.
4. Clean up.

## Create the extra record

First you create the extra record from scratch. As you mix several types, I used a POJO, here is the code:

```
List<ModelPrevisionRecord> data = new ArrayList<>();
ModelPrevisionRecord b = new ModelPrevisionRecord(
    -1L,
    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),
    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
data.add(b);
Dataset<ModelPrevisionRecord> ds = spark.createDataset(data,
    Encoders.bean(ModelPrevisionRecord.class));
timeDf = timeDf.unionByName(ds.toDF());
```

ModelPrevisionRecord is a very basic POJO:

```
package net.jgp.labs.spark.l999_scrapbook.l000;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class ModelPrevisionRecord {

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Timestamp getModel() {
    return model;
  }

  public void setModel(Timestamp model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  public Timestamp getPrevision() {
    return prevision;
  }

  public void setPrevision(Timestamp prevision) {
    this.prevision = prevision;
  }

  private long id;
  private Timestamp model;
  private Timestamp prevision;

  public ModelPrevisionRecord(long id, Timestamp model, Timestamp prevision) {
    this.id = id;
    this.model = model;
    this.prevision = prevision;
  }
}
```

## Correct the Id

The id is -1, so the id is to create a new column, `id2`, with the right id:

```
timeDf = timeDf.withColumn("id2",
    when(
        col("id").$eq$eq$eq(-1), timeDf.agg(max("id")).head().getLong(0)+1)
            .otherwise(col("id")));
```

## Cleanup the dataframe

Finally, clean up your dataframe:

```
timeDf = timeDf.drop("id").withColumnRenamed("id2", "id");
```

## Important notes

- This solution will only work if you add one record at a time, otherwise, you will end up having the same id.
- You can see the whole example here: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.labs.spark/tree/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/labs/spark/l999_scrapbook/l000, it might be easier to clone...

Answer (score 0):

If your first dataframe can be sorted by ID and you need to add rows one by one you can find maximum ID in your list:

```
long max = timeDF.agg(functions.max("Id")).head().getLong(0);
```

and then increment and add it to your dataframe by Union. To do this, follow the following example which age can act like id. `people.json` is a file in spark examples.

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("H:\\work\\HadoopWinUtils\\people.json");
df.show();

long max = df.agg(functions.max("age")).head().getLong(0);
List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(max+1,  "test"));

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.LongType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())));
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
df2.show();
Dataset<Row> df3 = df.union(df2);
df3.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but I got this type mismatch error : ```error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] (in java.util)
 required: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] (in scala.collection.immutable)
    val newTime: List[Row] = Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(id, modelTS, targetTS))```. How should I resolve such issue, they use same type but can't make it work.

Comment: You need change datatypes based your values. I use (Integer, String) as tuple. Just first test it by 'people.json' to see how work. All thing you need is `df.agg(max('ID'))`. However, this code is Java not Scala.

Comment: This error says I use List in `java.util` but you use List in `Scala.collections` which are different.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but I don't know why, when printing the table saved, it only keep the last 2 rows, all others being deleted.

This is how I init the delta table :

```scala
val schema = StructType(
               StructField("Id", LongType, false) ::
               StructField("Model", TimestampType, false) ::
               StructField("Prevision", TimestampType, false) :: Nil
             )

var timestampDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

val write_format = "delta"
val partition_by = "Model"
val save_path = "/mnt/path/to/folder"
val table_name = "myTable"

spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name)
dbutils.fs.rm(save_path, true)

timestampDF.write.partitionBy(partition_by)
                 .format(write_format)
                 .save(save_path)

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " USING DELTA LOCATION '" + save_path + "'")
```

And this how I add a new item to it

```scala
def addTimeToData(model: Calendar, target: Calendar): Unit = {
  var timeDF = spark.read
                    .format("delta")
                    .load("/mnt/path/to/folder")
  
  val modelTS = new Timestamp(model.getTimeInMillis)
  val targetTS = new Timestamp(target.getTimeInMillis)
  var id: Long = 0
  
  if (!timeDF.head(1).isEmpty) {
    id = timeDF.agg(max("Id")).head().getLong(0) + 1
  }
  
  val newTime = Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(id, modelTS, targetTS))
  val schema = StructType(
                 StructField("Id", LongType, false) ::
                 StructField("Model", TimestampType, false) ::
                 StructField("Prevision", TimestampType, false) :: Nil
               )  
  var newTimeDF = spark.createDataFrame(newTime, schema)
  val unionTimeDF = timeDF.union(newTimeDF)
  timeDF = unionTimeDF
  unionTimeDF.show
  val save_path = "/mnt/datalake/Exploration/Provisionning/MeteoFrance/Timestamps/"
  val table_name = "myTable"

  spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name)
  dbutils.fs.rm(save_path, true)
  timeDF.write.partitionBy("Model")
              .format("delta")
              .save(save_path)

  spark.sql("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " USING DELTA LOCATION '" + save_path + "'")
}
```

I'm not very familiar with delta tables so I don't know if I can just use SQL on it to add values like so :

```scala
spark.sql("INSERT INTO 'myTable' VALUES (" + id + ", " + modelTS + ", " + previsionTS + ")");
```

And I don't if just putting the timestamps variable like so will work.

Comment: Adrien - this is great, but it should be in your question, as an update! I don't think you need Delta. I'll try to work an answer...

Comment: I'm enforced to use Delta tables

Comment: post a new question with your additional need (Delta), then the code you tried (this answer), and shoot me the link, I'll try to do something (itm, you can validate my answer :D).